# How to add pdf file in text area?

Tags: php, jquery, html, kohana

I want to add `pdf` file or `docx` file on my text area. I hope guys you can help me. thank you ! if you wanted to check I mean it is located in my website [linkinads.com/publish-new.html](http://linkinads.com/publish-new.html)

[image]

---

```
<?if($form_show['description'] != FALSE):?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <?= FORM::label('description', _e('Description'), array('for'=>'description', 'spellcheck'=>TRUE))?>
            <?=FORM::textarea('description', Request::current()->post('description'), array('class'=>'form-control'.((Core::config("advertisement.description_bbcode"))? NULL:' disable-bbcode'), 
                'name'=>'description', 
                'id'=>'description', 
                'rows'=>10, 
                'required',
                'data-bannedwords' => (core::config('advertisement.validate_banned_words') AND core::config('advertisement.banned_words') != '') ? json_encode(explode(',', core::config('advertisement.banned_words'))) : '',
                'data-error' => __('This field must not contain banned words ({0})')))?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Which text editor are you using?

Comment: do you want to drag and drop pdf into your textarea?

Comment: yes. or i have to click something above on my txt area to upload pdf file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also found Javascript for my txtarea, I hope this will help more guys. Shall i Edit the JS...?

```
//sceditor $('textarea[name=description]:not(.disable-bbcode)').sceditorBBCodePlugin({ toolbar:: "bold,italic,underline,strike,|left,center,right,justify|" + 
"bulletlist,orderedlist|link,unlink,youtube|source",
resizeEnabled: "true",
emoticonsEnabled: false,
style: $('meta[name="application-name"]').data('baseurl') + "themes/default/css/jquery.sceditor.default.min.css",
width: '88%',
height: "300px"});
```